# My app is installed in emulator, but it doesn't start automatically

Tags: android, linux, android-emulator

Before asking this question I searched and found the following links: 

[MyFirstApp installed on emulator but can't launch it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13327499/myfirstapp-installed-on-emulator-but-cant-launch-it)
[Android app won't open after i install. But it can run in emulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9410378/android-app-wont-open-after-i-install-but-it-can-run-in-emulator)
[Android app not launching on emulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6203581/android-app-not-launching-on-emulator)

None of them solve my problem.

This is my first app, and I created it as a new androidProject. so the code doesn't have any problems. I use linux, and my console shows the following:

```
[2013-05-30 14:06:36 - Hello] Android Launch!
[2013-05-30 14:06:36 - Hello] adb is running normally.
[2013-05-30 14:06:36 - Hello] Performing com.example.hello.MainActivity activity launch
[2013-05-30 14:06:36 - Hello] Automatic Target Mode: Unable to detect device compatibility. Please select a target device.
[2013-05-30 14:06:39 - Hello] Uploading Hello.apk onto device 'emulator-5554'
[2013-05-30 14:06:40 - Hello] Installing Hello.apk...
[2013-05-30 14:07:26 - Hello] Success!
[2013-05-30 14:07:27 - Hello] Starting activity com.example.hello.MainActivity on device emulator-5554
```

`UPDATE 1`
When I ran project in my phone the app ran outo but did not run in the emulator. Why?

`UPDATE 2`
Waited for 15 minute (after end of console message) but does not solve my problem.

`UPDATE 3`
I tested some other projects too, but problem is not getting solved yet.

`UPDATE 4`
Logcat message -

```
0: I/ActivityManager(297): No longer want android.process.media (pid 585): empty for 1809s
0: I/ActivityManager(297): No longer want com.android.deskclock (pid 680): empty for 1809s
0: I/ActivityManager(297): No longer want com.android.settings (pid 810): empty for 1810s
0: D/ExchangeService(768): !!! EAS ExchangeService, onStartCommand, startingUp = false, running = false
0: W/ActivityManager(297): Unable to start service Intent { act=com.android.email.ACCOUNT_INTENT } U=0: not found
0: D/ExchangeService(768): !!! Email application not found; stopping self
0: W/ActivityManager(297): Unable to start service Intent { act=com.android.email.ACCOUNT_INTENT } U=0: not found
0: E/ActivityThread(768): Service com.android.exchange.ExchangeService has leaked ServiceConnection com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy$ProxyConnection@40d40c68 that was originally bound here
0: E/ActivityThread(768): android.app.ServiceConnectionLeaked: Service com.android.exchange.ExchangeService has leaked ServiceConnection com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy$ProxyConnection@40d40c68 that was originally bound here
0: E/ActivityThread(768):   at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher.<init>(LoadedApk.java:969)
0: E/ActivityThread(768):   at android.app.LoadedApk.getServiceDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:863)
0: E/ActivityThread(768):   at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1418)
0: E/ActivityThread(768):   at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1407)
0: E/ActivityThread(768):   at android.content.ContextWrapper.bindService(ContextWrapper.java:473)
0: E/ActivityThread(768):   at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.setTask(ServiceProxy.java:157)
06-04 17:10:32.895: E/ActivityThread(768):  at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.setTask(ServiceProxy.java:145)
06-04 17:10:32.895: E/ActivityThread(768):  at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.test(ServiceProxy.java:191)
06-04 17:10:32.895: E/ActivityThread(768):  at com.android.exchange.ExchangeService$7.run(ExchangeService.java:1850)
06-04 17:10:32.895: E/ActivityThread(768):  at com.android.emailcommon.utility.Utility$2.doInBackground(Utility.java:551)
06-04 17:10:32.895: E/ActivityThread(768):  at com.android.emailcommon.utility.Utility$2.doInBackground(Utility.java:549)
06-04 17:10:32.895: E/ActivityThread(768):  at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
06-04 17:10:32.895: E/ActivityThread(768):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
06-04 17:10:32.895: E/ActivityThread(768):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
06-04 17:10:32.895: E/ActivityThread(768):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
06-04 17:10:32.895: E/ActivityThread(768):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
06-04 17:10:33.685: E/StrictMode(768): null
06-04 17:10:33.685: E/StrictMode(768): android.app.ServiceConnectionLeaked: Service com.android.exchange.ExchangeService has leaked ServiceConnection com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy$ProxyConnection@40d40c68 that was originally bound here
06-04 17:10:33.685: E/StrictMode(768):  at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher.<init>(LoadedApk.java:969)
06-04 17:10:33.685: E/StrictMode(768):  at android.app.LoadedApk.getServiceDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:863)
06-04 17:10:33.685: E/StrictMode(768):  at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1418)
06-04 17:10:33.685: E/StrictMode(768):  at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1407)
06-04 17:10:33.685: E/StrictMode(768):  at android.content.ContextWrapper.bindService(ContextWrapper.java:473)
06-04 17:10:33.685: E/StrictMode(768):  at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.setTask(ServiceProxy.java:157)
06-04 17:10:33.685: E/StrictMode(768):  at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.setTask(ServiceProxy.java:145)
06-04 17:10:33.685: E/StrictMode(768):  at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.test(ServiceProxy.java:191)
06-04 17:10:33.685: E/StrictMode(768):  at com.android.exchange.ExchangeService$7.run(ExchangeService.java:1850)
06-04 17:10:33.685: E/StrictMode(768):  at com.android.emailcommon.utility.Utility$2.doInBackground(Utility.java:551)
06-04 17:10:33.685: E/StrictMode(768):  at com.android.emailcommon.utility.Utility$2.doInBackground(Utility.java:549)
06-04 17:10:33.685: E/StrictMode(768):  at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
06-04 17:10:33.685: E/StrictMode(768):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
06-04 17:10:33.685: E/StrictMode(768):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
06-04 17:10:33.685: E/StrictMode(768):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
06-04 17:10:33.685: E/StrictMode(768):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
06-04 17:10:33.795: W/ActivityManager(297): Unbind failed: could not find connection for android.os.BinderProxy@40fa9518
06-04 17:10:34.365: D/dalvikvm(768): GC_CONCURRENT freed 403K, 19% free 2486K/3068K, paused 106ms+73ms, total 1356ms
06-04 17:10:36.205: D/AndroidRuntime(1507): >>>>>> AndroidRuntime START com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit <<<<<<
06-04 17:10:36.215: D/AndroidRuntime(1507): CheckJNI is ON
06-04 17:10:36.654: D/dalvikvm(1507): Trying to load lib libjavacore.so 0x0
06-04 17:10:36.755: D/dalvikvm(1507): Added shared lib libjavacore.so 0x0
06-04 17:10:40.265: D/AndroidRuntime(1514): >>>>>> AndroidRuntime START com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit <<<<<<
06-04 17:10:40.275: D/AndroidRuntime(1514): CheckJNI is ON
06-04 17:10:40.635: D/dalvikvm(1514): Trying to load lib libjavacore.so 0x0
06-04 17:10:40.705: D/dalvikvm(1514): Added shared lib libjavacore.so 0x0
06-04 17:10:40.944: D/dalvikvm(1514): Trying to load lib libnativehelper.so 0x0
06-04 17:10:40.944: D/dalvikvm(1514): Added shared lib libnativehelper.so 0x0
06-04 17:10:47.597: D/AndroidRuntime(1514): Calling main entry com.android.commands.pm.Pm
06-04 17:10:47.815: I/ActivityManager(297): No longer want com.android.providers.calendar (pid 793): empty for 1805s
06-04 17:10:47.865: I/ActivityManager(297): No longer want com.android.calendar (pid 837): empty for 1805s
06-04 17:10:48.374: W/ActivityManager(297): No content provider found for permission revoke: file:///data/local/tmp/DatabaseActivity.apk
06-04 17:10:48.545: W/ActivityManager(297): No content provider found for permission revoke: file:///data/local/tmp/DatabaseActivity.apk
06-04 17:10:48.585: I/PackageManager(297): Copying native libraries to /data/app-lib/vmdl-1422685739
06-04 17:10:50.044: I/PackageManager(297): Removing non-system package:com.kamalan
06-04 17:10:50.054: I/ActivityManager(297): Force stopping package com.kamalan appid=10049 user=-1
06-04 17:10:51.095: I/PackageManager(297): Package com.kamalan codePath changed from /data/app/com.kamalan-2.apk to /data/app/com.kamalan-1.apk; Retaining data and using new
06-04 17:10:51.216: I/PackageManager(297): Running dexopt on: com.kamalan
06-04 17:10:54.445: D/dalvikvm(1528): DexOpt: load 553ms, verify+opt 1914ms, 285396 bytes
06-04 17:10:54.525: I/ActivityManager(297): Force stopping package com.kamalan appid=10049 user=-1
06-04 17:10:54.565: W/PackageManager(297): Code path for pkg : com.kamalan changing from /data/app/com.kamalan-2.apk to /data/app/com.kamalan-1.apk
06-04 17:10:54.605: W/PackageManager(297): Resource path for pkg : com.kamalan changing from /data/app/com.kamalan-2.apk to /data/app/com.kamalan-1.apk
06-04 17:10:55.605: D/dalvikvm(297): GC_CONCURRENT freed 637K, 32% free 5428K/7980K, paused 65ms+105ms, total 963ms
06-04 17:10:56.954: D/PackageManager(297): New package installed in /data/app/com.kamalan-1.apk
06-04 17:10:58.055: I/ActivityManager(297): Force stopping package com.kamalan appid=10049 user=0
06-04 17:10:58.205: D/dalvikvm(504): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 1ms
06-04 17:10:59.014: D/dalvikvm(444): GC_EXPLICIT freed 155K, 65% free 4400K/12456K, paused 40ms+97ms, total 701ms
06-04 17:10:59.885: I/InputReader(297): Reconfiguring input devices.  changes=0x00000010
06-04 17:11:00.225: W/ContextImpl(1112): Calling a method in the system process without a qualified user: android.app.ContextImpl.startService:1352 android.content.ContextWrapper.startService:450 android.content.ContextWrapper.startService:450 com.android.keychain.KeyChainBroadcastReceiver.onReceive:12 android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver:2376 
06-04 17:11:00.345: D/dalvikvm(504): GC_EXPLICIT freed 142K, 13% free 2691K/3088K, paused 60ms+122ms, total 2139ms
06-04 17:11:01.338: I/InputReader(297): Reconfiguring input devices.  changes=0x00000010
06-04 17:11:10.726: W/InputMethodManagerService(297): Found no subtypes in a system IME: com.android.inputmethod.pinyin
06-04 17:11:12.735: D/dalvikvm(444): GC_CONCURRENT freed 482K, 64% free 4488K/12456K, paused 48ms+114ms, total 688ms
06-04 17:11:15.934: D/dalvikvm(297): GC_EXPLICIT freed 734K, 33% free 5378K/7980K, paused 1139ms+211ms, total 8937ms
06-04 17:11:16.195: D/AndroidRuntime(1514): Shutting down VM
06-04 17:11:16.335: D/dalvikvm(1514): GC_CONCURRENT freed 91K, 17% free 459K/552K, paused 4ms+18ms, total 99ms
06-04 17:11:16.365: D/dalvikvm(1514): Debugger has detached; object registry had 1 entries
06-04 17:11:18.075: D/ExchangeService(768): Received deviceId from Email app: null
06-04 17:11:18.075: D/ExchangeService(768): !!! deviceId unknown; stopping self and retrying
06-04 17:11:20.495: I/Choreographer(444): Skipped 101 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
06-04 17:11:20.844: D/AndroidRuntime(1540): >>>>>> AndroidRuntime START com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit <<<<<<
06-04 17:11:20.864: D/AndroidRuntime(1540): CheckJNI is ON
06-04 17:11:21.335: I/Choreographer(444): Skipped 34 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
06-04 17:11:21.665: D/dalvikvm(1540): Trying to load lib libjavacore.so 0x0
06-04 17:11:21.816: D/dalvikvm(1540): Added shared lib libjavacore.so 0x0
06-04 17:11:22.265: D/dalvikvm(1540): Trying to load lib libnativehelper.so 0x0
06-04 17:11:22.265: D/dalvikvm(1540): Added shared lib libnativehelper.so 0x0
06-04 17:11:23.805: D/ExchangeService(768): !!! EAS ExchangeService, onStartCommand, startingUp = false, running = false
06-04 17:11:24.305: W/ActivityManager(297): Unable to start service Intent { act=com.android.email.ACCOUNT_INTENT } U=0: not found
06-04 17:11:24.385: W/RecognitionManagerService(297): no available voice recognition services found for user 0
06-04 17:11:24.427: D/ExchangeService(768): !!! Email application not found; stopping self
06-04 17:11:24.716: E/ActivityThread(768): Service com.android.exchange.ExchangeService has leaked ServiceConnection com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy$ProxyConnection@40d577c0 that was originally bound here
06-04 17:11:24.716: E/ActivityThread(768): android.app.ServiceConnectionLeaked: Service com.android.exchange.ExchangeService has leaked ServiceConnection com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy$ProxyConnection@40d577c0 that was originally bound here
06-04 17:11:24.716: E/ActivityThread(768):  at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher.<init>(LoadedApk.java:969)
06-04 17:11:24.716: E/ActivityThread(768):  at android.app.LoadedApk.getServiceDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:863)
06-04 17:11:24.716: E/ActivityThread(768):  at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1418)
06-04 17:11:24.716: E/ActivityThread(768):  at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1407)
06-04 17:11:24.716: E/ActivityThread(768):  at android.content.ContextWrapper.bindService(ContextWrapper.java:473)
06-04 17:11:24.716: E/ActivityThread(768):  at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.setTask(ServiceProxy.java:157)
06-04 17:11:24.716: E/ActivityThread(768):  at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.setTask(ServiceProxy.java:145)
06-04 17:11:24.716: E/ActivityThread(768):  at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.test(ServiceProxy.java:191)
06-04 17:11:24.716: E/ActivityThread(768):  at com.android.exchange.ExchangeService$7.run(ExchangeService.java:1850)
06-04 17:11:24.716: E/ActivityThread(768):  at com.android.emailcommon.utility.Utility$2.doInBackground(Utility.java:551)
06-04 17:11:24.716: E/ActivityThread(768):  at com.android.emailcommon.utility.Utility$2.doInBackground(Utility.java:549)
06-04 17:11:24.716: E/ActivityThread(768):  at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
06-04 17:11:24.716: E/ActivityThread(768):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
06-04 17:11:24.716: E/ActivityThread(768):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
06-04 17:11:24.716: E/ActivityThread(768):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
06-04 17:11:24.716: E/ActivityThread(768):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
06-04 17:11:24.785: W/ActivityManager(297): Unable to start service Intent { act=com.android.email.ACCOUNT_INTENT } U=0: not found
06-04 17:11:24.859: E/StrictMode(768): null
06-04 17:11:24.859: E/StrictMode(768): android.app.ServiceConnectionLeaked: Service com.android.exchange.ExchangeService has leaked ServiceConnection com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy$ProxyConnection@40d577c0 that was originally bound here
06-04 17:11:24.859: E/StrictMode(768):  at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher.<init>(LoadedApk.java:969)
06-04 17:11:24.859: E/StrictMode(768):  at android.app.LoadedApk.getServiceDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:863)
06-04 17:11:24.859: E/StrictMode(768):  at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1418)
06-04 17:11:24.859: E/StrictMode(768):  at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1407)
06-04 17:11:24.859: E/StrictMode(768):  at android.content.ContextWrapper.bindService(ContextWrapper.java:473)
06-04 17:11:24.859: E/StrictMode(768):  at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.setTask(ServiceProxy.java:157)
06-04 17:11:24.859: E/StrictMode(768):  at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.setTask(ServiceProxy.java:145)
06-04 17:11:24.859: E/StrictMode(768):  at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.test(ServiceProxy.java:191)
06-04 17:11:24.859: E/StrictMode(768):  at com.android.exchange.ExchangeService$7.run(ExchangeService.java:1850)
06-04 17:11:24.859: E/StrictMode(768):  at com.android.emailcommon.utility.Utility$2.doInBackground(Utility.java:551)
06-04 17:11:24.859: E/StrictMode(768):  at com.android.emailcommon.utility.Utility$2.doInBackground(Utility.java:549)
06-04 17:11:24.859: E/StrictMode(768):  at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
06-04 17:11:24.859: E/StrictMode(768):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
06-04 17:11:24.859: E/StrictMode(768):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
06-04 17:11:24.859: E/StrictMode(768):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
06-04 17:11:24.859: E/StrictMode(768):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
06-04 17:11:24.900: W/ActivityManager(297): Unbind failed: could not find connection for android.os.BinderProxy@40ce9800
06-04 17:11:38.775: W/ProcessStats(297): Skipping unknown process pid 1547
06-04 17:12:09.826: D/ExchangeService(768): Received deviceId from Email app: null
06-04 17:12:09.826: D/ExchangeService(768): !!! deviceId unknown; stopping self and retrying
06-04 17:12:15.018: D/ExchangeService(768): !!! EAS ExchangeService, onStartCommand, startingUp = false, running = false
06-04 17:12:15.085: W/ActivityManager(297): Unable to start service Intent { act=com.android.email.ACCOUNT_INTENT } U=0: not found
06-04 17:12:15.192: D/ExchangeService(768): !!! Email application not found; stopping self
06-04 17:12:15.435: W/ActivityManager(297): Unable to start service Intent { act=com.android.email.ACCOUNT_INTENT } U=0: not found
06-04 17:12:15.571: E/ActivityThread(768): Service com.android.exchange.ExchangeService has leaked ServiceConnection com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy$ProxyConnection@40d5f4b0 that was originally bound here
06-04 17:12:15.571: E/ActivityThread(768): android.app.ServiceConnectionLeaked: Service com.android.exchange.ExchangeService has leaked ServiceConnection com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy$ProxyConnection@40d5f4b0 that was originally bound here
06-04 17:12:15.571: E/ActivityThread(768):  at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher.<init>(LoadedApk.java:969)
06-04 17:12:15.571: E/ActivityThread(768):  at android.app.LoadedApk.getServiceDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:863)
06-04 17:12:15.571: E/ActivityThread(768):  at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1418)
06-04 17:12:15.571: E/ActivityThread(768):  at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1407)
06-04 17:12:15.571: E/ActivityThread(768):  at android.content.ContextWrapper.bindService(ContextWrapper.java:473)
06-04 17:12:15.571: E/ActivityThread(768):  at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.setTask(ServiceProxy.java:157)
06-04 17:12:15.571: E/ActivityThread(768):  at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.setTask(ServiceProxy.java:145)
06-04 17:12:15.571: E/ActivityThread(768):  at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.test(ServiceProxy.java:191)
06-04 17:12:15.571: E/ActivityThread(768):  at com.android.exchange.ExchangeService$7.run(ExchangeService.java:1850)
06-04 17:12:15.571: E/ActivityThread(768):  at com.android.emailcommon.utility.Utility$2.doInBackground(Utility.java:551)
06-04 17:12:15.571: E/ActivityThread(768):  at com.android.emailcommon.utility.Utility$2.doInBackground(Utility.java:549)
06-04 17:12:15.571: E/ActivityThread(768):  at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
06-04 17:12:15.571: E/ActivityThread(768):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
06-04 17:12:15.571: E/ActivityThread(768):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
06-04 17:12:15.571: E/ActivityThread(768):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
06-04 17:12:15.571: E/ActivityThread(768):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
06-04 17:12:15.999: E/StrictMode(768): null
06-04 17:12:15.999: E/StrictMode(768): android.app.ServiceConnectionLeaked: Service com.android.exchange.ExchangeService has leaked ServiceConnection com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy$ProxyConnection@40d5f4b0 that was originally bound here
06-04 17:12:15.999: E/StrictMode(768):  at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher.<init>(LoadedApk.java:969)
06-04 17:12:15.999: E/StrictMode(768):  at android.app.LoadedApk.getServiceDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:863)
06-04 17:12:15.999: E/StrictMode(768):  at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1418)
06-04 17:12:15.999: E/StrictMode(768):  at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1407)
06-04 17:12:15.999: E/StrictMode(768):  at android.content.ContextWrapper.bindService(ContextWrapper.java:473)
06-04 17:12:15.999: E/StrictMode(768):  at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.setTask(ServiceProxy.java:157)
06-04 17:12:15.999: E/StrictMode(768):  at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.setTask(ServiceProxy.java:145)
06-04 17:12:15.999: E/StrictMode(768):  at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.test(ServiceProxy.java:191)
06-04 17:12:15.999: E/StrictMode(768):  at com.android.exchange.ExchangeService$7.run(ExchangeService.java:1850)
06-04 17:12:15.999: E/StrictMode(768):  at com.android.emailcommon.utility.Utility$2.doInBackground(Utility.java:551)
06-04 17:12:15.999: E/StrictMode(768):  at com.android.emailcommon.utility.Utility$2.doInBackground(Utility.java:549)
06-04 17:12:15.999: E/StrictMode(768):  at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
06-04 17:12:15.999: E/StrictMode(768):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
06-04 17:12:15.999: E/StrictMode(768):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
06-04 17:12:15.999: E/StrictMode(768):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
06-04 17:12:15.999: E/StrictMode(768):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
06-04 17:12:16.267: W/ActivityManager(297): Unbind failed: could not find connection for android.os.BinderProxy@40fc18e0
```

AND then i read following links
[Android emulator spams logcat with "Service com.android.exchange.ExchangeService has leaked ServiceConnection ... that was originally bound here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13765122/various-android-logcat-errors)
[Android "No content provider found for permission revoke"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11550798/android-no-content-provider-found-for-permission-revoke)
first link work for me . but second link didnt work
so my Logcat show

```
06-04 18:15:04.209: D/AndroidRuntime(2671): >>>>>> AndroidRuntime START com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit <<<<<<
06-04 18:15:04.209: D/AndroidRuntime(2671): CheckJNI is ON
06-04 18:15:04.615: D/dalvikvm(2671): Trying to load lib libjavacore.so 0x0
06-04 18:15:04.705: D/dalvikvm(2671): Added shared lib libjavacore.so 0x0
06-04 18:15:05.025: D/dalvikvm(2671): Trying to load lib libnativehelper.so 0x0
06-04 18:15:05.025: D/dalvikvm(2671): Added shared lib libnativehelper.so 0x0
06-04 18:15:11.066: D/AndroidRuntime(2676): >>>>>> AndroidRuntime START com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit <<<<<<
06-04 18:15:11.066: D/AndroidRuntime(2676): CheckJNI is ON
06-04 18:15:11.415: D/dalvikvm(2676): Trying to load lib libjavacore.so 0x0
06-04 18:15:11.474: D/dalvikvm(2676): Added shared lib libjavacore.so 0x0
06-04 18:15:11.725: D/dalvikvm(2676): Trying to load lib libnativehelper.so 0x0
06-04 18:15:11.725: D/dalvikvm(2676): Added shared lib libnativehelper.so 0x0
06-04 18:15:16.085: D/AndroidRuntime(2676): Calling main entry com.android.commands.pm.Pm
06-04 18:15:16.435: W/ActivityManager(297): No content provider found for permission revoke: file:///data/local/tmp/Hello.apk
06-04 18:15:16.625: W/ActivityManager(297): No content provider found for permission revoke: file:///data/local/tmp/Hello.apk
06-04 18:15:16.656: I/PackageManager(297): Copying native libraries to /data/app-lib/vmdl1402094020
06-04 18:15:17.626: I/PackageManager(297): Removing non-system package:com.example.hello
06-04 18:15:17.626: I/ActivityManager(297): Force stopping package com.example.hello appid=10047 user=-1
06-04 18:15:18.254: I/PackageManager(297): Package com.example.hello codePath changed from /data/app/com.example.hello-2.apk to /data/app/com.example.hello-1.apk; Retaining data and using new
06-04 18:15:18.334: I/PackageManager(297): Running dexopt on: com.example.hello
06-04 18:15:24.745: D/dalvikvm(2689): DexOpt: load 1310ms, verify+opt 3731ms, 790652 bytes
06-04 18:15:24.865: W/PackageManager(297): Code path for pkg : com.example.hello changing from /data/app/com.example.hello-2.apk to /data/app/com.example.hello-1.apk
06-04 18:15:24.877: I/ActivityManager(297): Force stopping package com.example.hello appid=10047 user=-1
06-04 18:15:24.925: W/PackageManager(297): Resource path for pkg : com.example.hello changing from /data/app/com.example.hello-2.apk to /data/app/com.example.hello-1.apk
06-04 18:15:25.565: D/PackageManager(297): New package installed in /data/app/com.example.hello-1.apk
06-04 18:15:26.335: I/ActivityManager(297): Force stopping package com.example.hello appid=10047 user=0
06-04 18:15:26.958: D/dalvikvm(2485): GC_EXPLICIT freed 139K, 13% free 2688K/3072K, paused 40ms+51ms, total 560ms
06-04 18:15:27.895: I/InputReader(297): Reconfiguring input devices.  changes=0x00000010
06-04 18:15:28.144: D/dalvikvm(444): GC_EXPLICIT freed 136K, 66% free 4474K/13056K, paused 47ms+478ms, total 1533ms
06-04 18:15:28.535: W/ContextImpl(1112): Calling a method in the system process without a qualified user: android.app.ContextImpl.startService:1352 android.content.ContextWrapper.startService:450 android.content.ContextWrapper.startService:450 com.android.keychain.KeyChainBroadcastReceiver.onReceive:12 android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver:2376 
06-04 18:15:28.745: D/dalvikvm(297): GC_CONCURRENT freed 767K, 27% free 5857K/7980K, paused 556ms+164ms, total 1945ms
06-04 18:15:31.248: I/InputReader(297): Reconfiguring input devices.  changes=0x00000010
06-04 18:15:33.840: W/InputMethodManagerService(297): Found no subtypes in a system IME: com.android.inputmethod.pinyin
06-04 18:15:38.765: D/dalvikvm(297): GC_EXPLICIT freed 380K, 28% free 5814K/7980K, paused 1380ms+200ms, total 5730ms
06-04 18:15:39.234: D/AndroidRuntime(2676): Shutting down VM
06-04 18:15:39.459: D/dalvikvm(2676): GC_CONCURRENT freed 91K, 17% free 459K/552K, paused 7ms+5ms, total 146ms
06-04 18:15:39.485: D/jdwp(2676): Got wake-up signal, bailing out of select
06-04 18:15:39.485: D/dalvikvm(2676): Debugger has detached; object registry had 1 entries
06-04 18:15:45.205: D/dalvikvm(444): GC_CONCURRENT freed 527K, 66% free 4527K/13056K, paused 70ms+155ms, total 791ms
06-04 18:15:45.314: D/AndroidRuntime(2701): >>>>>> AndroidRuntime START com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit <<<<<<
06-04 18:15:45.345: D/AndroidRuntime(2701): CheckJNI is ON
06-04 18:15:46.545: I/Choreographer(444): Skipped 326 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
06-04 18:15:47.335: I/Choreographer(444): Skipped 58 frames!  The application may be  doing too much work on its main thread.
06-04 18:15:47.625: W/RecognitionManagerService(297): no available voice recognition services found for user 0
```

I am very tired to fix it.
My manifest file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.com.hello"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.hello.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

setting of my emulator4.2.2

```
avd.ini.encoding=ISO-8859-1
hw.dPad=no
hw.lcd.density=160
hw.cpu.arch=arm
hw.device.hash=-1537072293
disk.dataPartition.size=200M
skin.path=1024x600
skin.dynamic=yes
hw.cpu.model=cortex-a8
hw.keyboard=yes
hw.ramSize=512
hw.device.manufacturer=Generic
hw.sdCard=no
hw.mainKeys=no
hw.accelerometer=yes
skin.name=1024x600
abi.type=armeabi-v7a
hw.trackBall=no
hw.device.name=7in WSVGA (Tablet)
hw.battery=yes
hw.sensors.proximity=yes
image.sysdir.1=system-images/android-17/armeabi-v7a/
hw.sensors.orientation=yes
hw.audioInput=yes
hw.camera.front=none
hw.gps=yes
vm.heapSize=32
snapshot.present=true
```

thanks to all
‍‍‍‍

Comment: @ jeevamuthu I added console to post

Comment: Can you see your app installed in the emulator? can u run it by selecting the App?

Comment: @ Santhosh Ok i can run it by click on it.

Comment: Do you see any "waiting for debugger to settle messages..." in LogCat? Or even the "Debugger has connected" message shown just as the application begins initialising?

Comment: @ lucian.pantelimon when i run by emolator i can not see any thing in logcat

Comment: You may simply have to wait.  The emulator can be painfully slow.  You can also try to start the app from the launcher on the emulator.  Also - more in response to comments than your question itself - I'd generally recommend that you "run" apps rather than "debug" them unless you particularly expect to need interactive debug capability and its overhead.

Comment: @ Chris Stratton wait for 15 minute (after showing end of console message) can not solves problem.

Comment: And there are no further logcat messages beyond the "Starting activity" message you posted above?  Even with all logcat filtering disabled?  What sorts of things does your app do?  If you build the most trivial SDK sample, will that work on your emulator?

Comment: @Chris Stratton I test some other App such as helloWorld and other App that I test it on windows and there work goodly but on linux dont work(working means dont auto lunched). by all logcat filtering disabled my logcat dont show anything. but when i ran it on my phone every thing is ok.my App is very simple that i sure its code is ok.

Comment: It sounds like your emulator configuration on the linux system is not right.  And if there are no further logcat messages if you run without filtering (run it from a terminal to be sure) then something is **definitely** wrong - logcat is always quite noisy during application startup.

Comment: @ Chris Stratton @  lucian.pantelimon problem of logcat solved

Comment: @MM-BB : Can you please paste your manifest code here?

Comment: what are your emulator and pc specs? and what options do you have enabled in the AVD creation menu? try creating a new emulator with different specs

Comment: @ nidhi Ok.but it dont have problem

Comment: In your manifest file, change manifest tag com.com.hello to com.example.hello and in your activity, change it com.com.hello.MainActivity to com.example.hello.MainActivity

Comment: @ Tamilselvan by changing it problem not solved

Comment: @ androidcompile No .dont work.please read question again (first link work for me . but second link didnt work)

Answer (score 1):

first you can download Android sdk
http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html#download
after you can download eclipse Juno download and run through after you can download all the file and add a new installation after you download all file adk all kit after lunch your program after your program will be run on emulator, i think you have some mistake doing to do this process go through detail and try to once more doing it .i'll give you a best link to provide you to all android application information .
http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/index.html

Comment: @ priya I downloaded sdk and eclipse from above link .Are you say me to download it again?

Comment: @ priya your way remain only. but i think is not best way. +1 thanks and +50

Answer (score 0):

Try this from command line when emulator starts:

```
adb shell chmod 777 /data/local
```

Then try to run your app once again.
It seems like there is a problem with your emulator.

Comment: @ androidcompile No .dont work.please read question again (first link work for me . but second link didnt work)

Answer (score 0):

Try using different VM with different versions of sdk and different settings